# What is -quiet in TCL

Tags: tcl, synopsys-vcs, programming-pearls

I need what below if statement gives true or false, Also please explain about "quiet"

```
if {[sizeof_collection[get_pins $source-quiet]]>0}
```

What is gives?
Note:-
`$source` is `I_TEST_MODE4`.

Comment: You'd have to look up the documentation for `get_pins` in whatever tool or library you're using. It's not part of standard tcl.

Comment: Are you sure it's `$source-quiet` and not `$source -quiet`?

Comment: Tcl cares very much about spaces as word separators; what spaces are missing in what you pasted? (The answer to your question depends on `get_pins` behaviour, or on your specific application/data.)

Answer (score 0):

If I assume spaces in the obvious places and other minor syntactic matters, your code snippet is:

```
if {[sizeof_collection [get_pins $source -quiet]] > 0} {
   # more stuff...
}
```

I can find, with a few seconds on a web search, a description of `get_pins` that mentions that `-quiet` is an option it supports. Without diving in further — I don't use Synopsis at all — I'd guess that `-quiet` suppresses diagnostic messages (e.g., on an empty result) so that the only output produced is the collection of pins on the source, which is then measured using `sizeof_collection` and checked against zero (as a non-emptiness check). That would be a comprehensible pattern.

Comment: Note that neither `get_pins` nor `sizeof_collection` are standard parts of Tcl at all. They're both specific to a stack of software that runs on/with Tcl, which is probably some form of Synopsis.